# Get an element from an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following php array:

```
Array ( [count] => 1 [0] => antwest@cisco.com )
```

All I need to do is get the email address out as a php string variable.

Surely this is something easy, could I use splice or something similar?

How can I do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Doesn't `$email = $yourArray[0];` work?

Comment: please read this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: looking at your previous questions you seem to think this is a tutorial site. at the rate you are going it will take a very long time to get anywhere

Answer (score 5):

The email address lies in `$array[0]`.

Basics of PHP, come on =D

Comment: Basics of any language that has arrays, really :P

Comment: Sounds like a troll to me...